# Setting attribute via a ClientScript not persisting

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My fixture has a ClientScript that sets an attribute on an element (the element comes from the script doing a `document.querySelectorAll(...)`):

```
element.setAttribute("data-foo", 'foo');
```

Later in testcafe-land when I try to access that element using a `Selector` it's always `null`:

```
const element = await Selector('[data-foo="foo"]')();
```

I've stuck a `debugger` statement into my injected ClientScript and as I step thru the function I see the element does indeed get the attribute added but as soon as I let the execution continue and try to find it again in the devtools Console the attribute is gone from the element.

I -think- it has to do with the iframe/shadow DOM? testcafe is creating?  I see there is a sub-iframe/execution context in chrome devtools - my ClientScript is being injected into `window.top` but there is a testcafe-created `iframe` in the mix too.

ANY THOUGHTS how I can get this to work?  I want an injected script to manipulate the DOM (by adding an attribute) that later on I want a testcafe `Selector` to select.  Why doesn't this work and how can I get it working???
thanks!!!
  Mark

Answer (score 1):

[TestCafe injects custom scripts into the `head` tag](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts.html#access-dom-in-the-injected-scripts). These scripts are executed before DOM is loaded.

Here is an example of how to manipulate DOM using the client script:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const scriptContent = `
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var p = document.querySelector('p');
    
    p.setAttribute("data-foo", 'foo');
});
`;

fixture `My fixture`
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/')
    .clientScripts({ content: scriptContent });

test('My test', async t => {
    const el = await Selector('[data-foo="foo"]');

    await t
        .expect(el.textContent).eql('This webpage is used as a sample in TestCafe tutorials.');
});
```